# AWS S3 Upload Multipart File Standard - Infrequent Access PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I upload a big file in Standard - Infrequent Access?

My code:

```
require('aws/aws-autoloader.php');

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => $key,
        'secret' => $secret,
    ),
));

$uploader = new MultipartUploader($client, $filename, [
    'bucket' => $bucket,
    'key'    => $filename,
    'part_size' => 1073741824,
]);
$uploader->upload();
```

The file upload OK, but in Standard mode and I want to upload in Infrequent Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a callback hook¹ that you need to use to set additonal options, like storage class.

```
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($client, $filename, [
    'bucket' => $bucket,
    'key'    => $filename,
    'before_initiate' => function (\Aws\Command $command) {
        // $command is a CreateMultipartUpload operation
        $command['StorageClass'] = 'STANDARD_IA';
     },
   'part_size' => 1073741824,
]);
```

Sources:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#createmultipartupload

---

¹ *callback hook* is a term that I may or may not have just now made up, and may or may not actually be what it's called, but it seems to describe this mechanism. I'm not a PHP specialist.